# SQL select column with expression

Tags: sql

I need to do a `SELECT` like :

```
Select 
   col1, col2, (expression) as colA 
from tablex ,
```

but the expression depends on an external variable `@per` so, the select would be something like :

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2,
    case 
        @per = 1 then (col00 + col01) as colA
        @per = 2 then (col00 + col01 + col02) as colA
        @per = 3 then (col00 + col01 + col02 + col03) as colA
    end 
FROM tableX
```

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: col1, col2, col00, col01, col02 and col03 belong to tableX

Comment: what is your programing language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code assuming you are using T-SQL:

```
SELECT col1,col2,
    case 
        WHEN @per =1 then (col00+col01) 
        WHEN @per =2 then (col00+col01+col02)
        WHEN @per =3 then (col00+col01+col02+col03)
    end as colA
FROM tableX
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  col1,col2, colA = 
  CASE @per
     WHEN 1 THEN (col00+col01) 
     WHEN 2 THEN (col00+col01+col02) 
     WHEN 3 THEN (col00+col01+col02+col03) 
     ELSE 0
  END   
FROM tableX
```